# unity switching to android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

my project was fine tell I switched it to android platform
scene view and game view are making everything lagging
and getting allot of (scene view .repaint ) (game view .repaint )

everything is fine when I close them , but I need them to complete my work ;)

what should I do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the best thing to do. Go to build sittings and make asset import overrides 256 and force fast compressor.